# Understanding traceroute output / high latency vs blizzard server

Tags: macos, traceroute

I've been trying to read about understand the output of the traceroute command on the mac but i really can't understand it very well.

I'm experiencing terrible latency connecting to the diablo 3 server so i decided to check if it was a network issue. Here is what the trace route looks like (it has not even completed yet! been doing it for over 10 min now):

```
traceroute -S -q 30 12.129.209.68

traceroute to 12.129.209.68 (12.129.209.68), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets

 1  dlinkrouter (192.168.0.1)  1.285 ms  0.851 ms  0.654 ms  0.676 ms  0.664 ms  0.623 ms *  4.297 ms  0.794 ms  0.737 ms  1.369 ms  0.717 ms *  0.961 ms  0.757 ms  8.706 ms  1.651 ms  2.063 ms *  0.998 ms  0.807 ms  0.697 ms  0.667 ms  8.713 ms *  0.963 ms  0.693 ms  0.748 ms  1.813 ms  1.341 ms (13% loss)
 2  24.13.248.1 (24.13.248.1)  36.272 ms  48.789 ms  33.085 ms  28.662 ms  35.509 ms  38.436 ms  32.023 ms  38.638 ms  30.408 ms  30.415 ms  29.989 ms  45.501 ms  34.335 ms  35.608 ms  30.944 ms  26.487 ms  37.454 ms  36.086 ms  33.028 ms  29.914 ms  38.346 ms  21.533 ms  24.997 ms  34.853 ms  32.122 ms  27.742 ms  29.929 ms  35.727 ms  34.138 ms  29.824 ms (0% loss)
 3  te-0-7-0-12-sur03.wchicago.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.85.131.97)  20.079 ms  18.979 ms  22.588 ms  12.373 ms  14.827 ms  28.472 ms  31.376 ms  15.214 ms  14.769 ms  14.792 ms  15.078 ms  15.224 ms  14.851 ms  19.789 ms  17.446 ms  12.459 ms  19.976 ms  14.391 ms  17.300 ms  98.946 ms  53.875 ms  19.463 ms  28.349 ms  73.952 ms  136.020 ms  16.908 ms  19.907 ms  15.279 ms  14.643 ms  19.251 ms (0% loss)
 4  te-2-4-0-0-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.105)  20.827 ms
    te-9-2-ur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (68.86.184.25)  16.178 ms
    te-2-4-0-1-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.109)  25.208 ms
    68.87.233.225 (68.87.233.225)  24.209 ms
    te-0-11-0-3-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.53)  23.843 ms
    te-9-3-ur02.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (68.86.184.65)  18.798 ms
    te-0-11-0-0-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.45)  20.391 ms
    te-9-2-ur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (68.86.184.25)  16.750 ms
    te-0-11-0-5-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (69.139.234.45)  29.354 ms
    te-0-11-0-3-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.53)  20.600 ms
    te-0-11-0-5-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (69.139.234.45)  26.235 ms
    te-0-11-0-2-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.133)  13.060 ms  18.419 ms
    te-0-11-0-1-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.129)  18.698 ms
    te-9-2-ur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (68.86.184.25)  22.390 ms
    te-0-11-0-7-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (69.139.234.53)  32.293 ms
    te-0-11-0-1-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.129)  20.431 ms
    68.87.233.225 (68.87.233.225)  17.970 ms
    te-0-11-0-2-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.87.210.133)  21.860 ms
    te-9-2-ur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (68.86.184.25)  22.910 ms
    te-2-4-0-2-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.57)  16.266 ms
    te-0-0-0-7-sur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (69.139.185.97)  20.741 ms
    te-0-4-0-7-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.102)  18.784 ms  18.984 ms
    68.87.233.225 (68.87.233.225)  26.196 ms
    te-2-4-0-2-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.57)  28.645 ms
    te-0-4-0-7-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.102)  15.954 ms
    te-0-0-0-7-sur01.beechgrove.in.indiana.comcast.net (69.139.185.97)  26.687 ms
    te-0-11-0-5-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (69.139.234.45)  22.738 ms
    te-0-11-0-0-ar01.elmhurst.il.chicago.comcast.net (68.86.189.45)  15.411 ms (0% loss)
 5  he-2-3-0-0-cr01.chicago.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.94.105)  20.479 ms  18.817 ms  19.930 ms  29.958 ms  18.159 ms  21.751 ms  22.917 ms  17.389 ms  19.469 ms  23.595 ms  26.163 ms  20.067 ms  29.902 ms  30.979 ms  18.921 ms  29.916 ms  19.931 ms  16.418 ms  20.578 ms  34.432 ms  28.448 ms  19.828 ms  19.560 ms  19.894 ms  95.644 ms  47.332 ms  44.162 ms  31.273 ms  34.742 ms  24.776 ms (0% loss)
 6  be-10406-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.84.210)  21.556 ms  20.012 ms  18.730 ms  39.995 ms  16.797 ms  23.045 ms  19.937 ms  20.971 ms  29.200 ms  92.498 ms  40.030 ms  29.390 ms  27.427 ms  25.531 ms  34.319 ms  20.014 ms  19.638 ms  20.114 ms  13.617 ms  113.966 ms  29.452 ms  32.467 ms  34.831 ms  35.079 ms  16.793 ms  23.667 ms  21.749 ms  113.021 ms  89.392 ms  24.869 ms (0% loss)
 7  pos-1-5-0-0-pe01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.87.126)  19.928 ms  37.150 ms  31.251 ms  28.122 ms  35.833 ms  31.589 ms  16.065 ms  42.077 ms  17.805 ms  19.971 ms  21.139 ms  18.641 ms  13.688 ms  16.417 ms  19.711 ms  30.032 ms  19.859 ms  14.229 ms  15.237 ms  20.322 ms  21.898 ms  18.903 ms  18.894 ms  19.300 ms  20.445 ms  24.459 ms  16.118 ms  30.495 ms  13.366 ms  15.318 ms (0% loss)
 8  192.205.37.21 (192.205.37.21)  19.219 ms  23.286 ms  20.077 ms  19.937 ms  19.925 ms  20.790 ms  18.804 ms  21.980 ms  18.253 ms  19.740 ms  17.148 ms  87.121 ms  17.846 ms  27.635 ms  18.066 ms  21.855 ms  20.401 ms  21.732 ms  17.767 ms  19.956 ms  21.674 ms  31.599 ms  16.441 ms  20.028 ms  19.931 ms  19.966 ms  27.931 ms  62.821 ms  19.158 ms  21.558 ms (0% loss)
 9  cr1.cgcil.ip.att.net (12.122.133.106)  78.163 ms  328.826 ms  86.049 ms  154.304 ms  93.938 ms  99.166 ms  74.121 ms  84.640 ms *  136.852 ms  69.940 ms  190.047 ms  73.941 ms  75.432 ms  69.837 ms  78.659 ms  71.109 ms  74.638 ms  72.068 ms  72.964 ms  68.254 ms  71.496 ms  69.815 ms  79.917 ms  72.758 ms  68.535 ms  78.230 ms  69.914 ms  69.737 ms  69.997 ms (3% loss)
10  cr2.dvmco.ip.att.net (12.122.31.85)  69.864 ms  68.813 ms  69.821 ms  73.463 ms  76.285 ms  84.049 ms  70.574 ms  241.154 ms  83.489 ms  69.815 ms  69.841 ms  70.018 ms  99.717 ms  89.750 ms  73.681 ms  75.658 ms  69.788 ms  79.758 ms  75.077 ms  74.889 ms  69.637 ms  69.990 ms  69.873 ms  69.920 ms  69.888 ms  69.705 ms  76.421 ms  73.219 ms  72.506 ms  77.370 ms (0% loss)
11  cr1.slkut.ip.att.net (12.122.30.25)  69.937 ms  287.612 ms  220.163 ms  83.616 ms  80.139 ms  76.013 ms  69.890 ms  69.902 ms  70.760 ms  68.856 ms  69.790 ms  70.092 ms  76.814 ms  80.694 ms  72.048 ms  73.552 ms  77.607 ms  70.925 ms  73.139 ms  88.302 ms  75.655 ms  69.676 ms  69.897 ms  257.302 ms  178.104 ms  73.810 ms  69.986 ms  69.873 ms  85.571 ms  71.308 ms (0% loss)
12  cr2.la2ca.ip.att.net (12.122.30.30)  83.052 ms  71.236 ms  68.516 ms  71.025 ms  70.990 ms  83.684 ms  72.760 ms  71.505 ms  78.234 ms  82.177 ms  77.582 ms  79.622 ms  80.885 ms  77.329 ms  81.578 ms  69.822 ms  69.971 ms  77.477 ms  72.064 ms  70.029 ms  89.810 ms  75.382 ms  74.406 ms  72.987 ms  343.647 ms *  170.027 ms  75.069 ms  79.337 ms  79.860 ms (3% loss)
13  gar5.lsrca.ip.att.net (12.122.85.33)  107.520 ms  97.897 ms  91.460 ms  189.031 ms  88.375 ms  121.095 ms  79.878 ms  69.744 ms  68.506 ms  73.403 ms  73.679 ms  73.914 ms  161.755 ms  78.763 ms  261.069 ms  77.027 ms  71.908 ms  78.297 ms  73.202 ms  81.775 ms  74.569 ms  65.852 ms  86.082 ms  81.912 ms  72.421 ms  71.999 ms  66.033 ms  90.563 ms  67.584 ms  66.525 ms (0% loss)
14  12-122-254-230.attens.net (12.122.254.230)  69.834 ms  72.853 ms  82.818 ms  78.173 ms  81.549 ms  67.891 ms  69.774 ms  68.836 ms  263.983 ms  253.871 ms  72.343 ms  69.894 ms  71.692 ms  87.182 ms  253.431 ms  124.961 ms  81.903 ms  138.694 ms  236.603 ms  76.039 ms  72.774 ms  69.362 ms  72.461 ms  73.024 ms  235.624 ms  224.965 ms  118.005 ms  70.012 ms  73.650 ms  73.527 ms (0% loss)
15  206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  72.428 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  82.013 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  71.346 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  69.616 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  76.057 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  358.375 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  90.991 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  261.155 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  74.149 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  366.088 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  314.918 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  71.893 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  66.371 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  78.904 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  72.562 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  71.763 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  75.011 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  67.743 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  75.033 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  181.959 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  74.160 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  71.419 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  185.633 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  149.127 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  281.522 ms
    mdf001c7613r0004-gig-12-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.246)  121.726 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  81.836 ms
    206.16.68.50 (206.16.68.50)  113.801 ms
    206.16.68.42 (206.16.68.42)  85.344 ms
    mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net (12.129.193.242)  76.399 ms (0% loss)
16  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
17  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
18  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
19  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
20  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
21  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
22  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
23  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
24  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
25  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
26  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
27  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
28  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
29  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * (100% loss)
```

So i guess my question is, should i try to call comcast and tell them i'm having terrible network issues and here is my trace route or this trace route is complete fine and i should just accept it.

Comment: Your logs does not show any problems, you have sub 300ms pings all the way up to Blizzards internal network. It is perfectly normal for a private internal routers not to respond with ICMP packets (hops 16 through 20). The more useful thing to see would be the results from `ping 12.129.209.68`

Comment: thanks! I'm right in front of my router, any ideas why i have 13% loss packages from what i understand is my router? Maybe that can be the problem of my latency?

Comment: Ah, did not scroll to the right and saw that 13%. That is usually explained by a overloaded home router, are you running a torrent program on one or more computers? Many home routers can only support 200 or 300 concurrent connections, a busy torrent can easily get over that number. When that happens your home router will start dropping packets.

Comment: Nop, right now the only one thing happening at home is netflix streaming, i have a ton of download speed (50mbps) so i would assume that should not affect? i could be totally wrong though